# How to add python code in template in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

Please tell me that can I write this code in html page or not, If I can write thewn Please show me a simple example.

```
while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

> template:

```
 {% while True %}
     {% for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"] %}
         {{i}}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endwhile %}
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with an endless loop? This wouldn't even work in a back end without locking your application.

Comment: It's not working. I want to show moving characters

Comment: Django isn't client end, it takes the template tags and then renders HTML which it pushes to your user's browser. An endless loop means it will never finish and won't render the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/)

```
{% for item in some_list %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has its own Jinja-like template languages that you must use in your templates. It is purposefully different / less capable than Python as you should not have complex logic in your template files.

Unfortunately your desired output seems to indicate that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the traditional [request-response](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_messages.htm) nature of HTTP. You'd probably want to write some JavaScript to dynamically alter the page content after it loads.